# Linked list program ends with segmentation fault

Tags: c, list

My first linked list program ends with segmentation fault error, could you point how to fix it.
Here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct list {
    int data;
    struct list *next;
} list;

list *add_to_list (list *head, int data) {
    list *node = malloc(sizeof(list));
    if (head == NULL) {
        printf("ERROR: malloc failed in to add_to_list\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    node -> data = data;
    node -> next = head;
    return node;
}

void print_list (list *head) {
    list *cur = head;
    while (cur) {
        printf("%d\n", cur -> data);
        cur = cur -> next;
    }
}

int main () {

    list node;
    scanf("%d", &node.data);
    add_to_list(&node, node.data);
    print_list(&node);
    return 0;
}
```

Actually I got no idea how to fix it.

Comment: Did you try step-by-step debugging?

Comment: This seems like a perfect time to learn how to [*debug*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) your programs. For example by using a [*debugger*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) to step through the code line by line while monitoring variables and their values.

Comment: I also recommend you debug while using pencil and paper to draw all operations. Use labeled boxes for variables and nodes, and arrows for all pointers. Erase and redraw the arrows as you modify the pointers, erase boxes as nodes are removed and deleted. If all pointers are properly (and *explicitly*) initialized to begin with, the drawing should help you find out when and where things start to go wrong.

Comment: And I especially recommend you take a ***very*** close look at the `add_to_list` function. The function and the way you use it is flawed, in multiple ways.

Comment: This is a common and complex way of writing this type of code. A linked list is a possibly empty collection of `nodes`. A node is not a list. A list is not a node. The data is not the node. Do you have a book on data structures? [see example code in this answer]( https://stackoverflow.com/a/76983776/11234199). Your code does not even have a list! Just a `struct` for a node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first node `next` member has "garbage" content, since you didn't initilize it. This will solve your problem:

```
int main () {
    list node;
    node.next = NULL;
    scanf("%d", &node.data);
    add_to_list(&node, node.data);
    print_list(&node);
    return 0;
}
```

Although using a debugger is an important skill for a programmer, as other users pointed out in the comments to your question, just by the behavior of your program it is possible to identify the problem. See, when iterating through the list, an unknown value is presented. This indicates that one more output is being processed in the iteration, that is, your while ends in the wrong way or your program crashes. In other words, your termination condition is probably not being met. As this condition involves checking whether the `next` member is `null`, the problem is probably there and is, in fact, what was happening.

I would reimplement your list in this way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct list_node {
    int data;
    struct list_node *next;
} list_node;

typedef struct list {
    list_node *head;
    list_node *tail;
} list;

void add_to_list( list *li, int data ) {

    list_node *new_node = (list_node*) malloc( sizeof(list_node) );

    if ( new_node == NULL ) {
        printf("ERROR: malloc failed in to add_to_list\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    new_node->data = data;
    new_node->next = NULL;

    if ( li->tail == NULL ) { // empty list
        li->head = new_node;
        li->tail = new_node;
    } else {
        li->head->next = new_node;
        li->head = new_node;
    }

}

void print_list( list *li ) {
    list_node *cur = li->tail;
    while ( cur != NULL ) {
        printf("%d\n", cur->data);
        cur = cur->next;
    }
}

int main() {

    list li;
    li.head = NULL;
    li.tail = NULL;

    for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
        add_to_list( &li, i );
    }

    print_list( &li );

    return 0;

}
```

In my implementation, the tail of the list represents the first element and the head the last. The list grows from left to right. I also split the implementation of your structure into two: one for the list itself and the other for the nodes in the list.

```
      ---  next
node | d | --->
      ---
                    list
 ----------------------------------------
|  tail                           head   |
|    |                              |    |
|   ---  next  ---  next     next  ---   |
|  | 0 | ---> | 1 | ---> ... ---> | 9 |  |
|   ---        ---                 ---   |
 ----------------------------------------
```